# how to use the trained model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, classification

```
img_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img, label],
                                        batch_size=128,capacity=2000,
                                        min_after_dequeue=1000)

logits = cifar10.inference(img_batch)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
saver.restore(sess,"/Tensorflow/cata.tfmodel")

tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
```

I have trained the model "cata.tfmodel" in another program and restored the sess in this program, but I don't know how to use this model to classify one picture and output the classification. 
The type of my dataset is tfrecords and read it by queue.

I'm confused that if I covert one picture into tfrecords, it will contain image and label, what to do next?

```
logits = cifar10.inference(img_batch)
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
```

Besides, If I delete logits , saver will throw ValueError: No variables to save